# Execute windows command in command prompt using php

Tags: php

The command below is working from the command prompt. How can I execute this from php using the command prompt.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\DBConvert\SQLite2MySQLSync\SQLite2MySQLSync_Cons.exe"/Session:"session"
```

I tried as below, but neither attempt works. Can you suggest the correct format?

```
1)exec('C:\Program Files (x86)\DBConvert\SQLite2MySQLSync\SQLite2MySQLSync_Cons.exe "'/Session:session'"');

2)system("C:\Program Files (x86)\DBConvert\SQLite2MySQLSync\SQLite2MySQLSync_Cons.exe /Session:session",$status);
```

Comment: Ouch, Windows... this hurts :(

Comment: Take a look at notes for Windows http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php#101579 or, a lot better solution, use Linux or Macintosh

Comment: @Nemoden: sorry , i cant unserstand this .. :(

Comment: exec('C:\Program Files (x86)\DBConvert\SQLite2MySQLSync\SQLite2MySQLSync_Cons.exe "'/Session:session'"'); how can i rearrange this to get it work?

Comment: Just as I said, read the official documentation on how to use exec on Windows. I guess you should pass you command to windows's `cmd` somehow. Comment from the official documentation says `just do: exec('start /B "window_name" "path to your exe"',$output,$return);` did you try it?

Comment: yes i did ..                                                   $session = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\DBConvert\SQLite2MySQLSync\SQLite2MySQLSync_Cons.exe" /Session:"session"';                                                    exec($session); But no luck.Not working.

Comment: this is not what you were implied to do, how assigning a variable can help executing an external command?

Answer (score 1):

I found a number of solutions work when trying to execute a command from the prompt, but it depends on the version of windows you are using. This is the way I run commands through php that I know work from the command prompt. You need to have the COM extension enabled in php5.4+. The hardest part, I find, is making sure you have the correct number of backslashes everywhere. I usually echo out the $runCommand in order to test the output before I get disappointed with the syntax not quite being correct.

```
// -- Windows command prompt action -- //
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$data='C:\Program Files (x86)\DBConvert\SQLite2MySQLSync\SQLite2MySQLSync_Cons.exe /Session:session';
$runCommand = "c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /C ".$data;
$output = $WshShell->Run($runCommand, 0, false);    
// -- end Windows command prompt action -- //
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look at the [**command library**](https://github.com/tivie/command) I wrote specifically for this. (sorry for the shameless pub)

It harmonizes OS differences and tries to workaround some nasty windows bugs. It also let's you access stdout, stdin and stderr even when using exec under windows.

For instance, in your case:

```
use Tivie\Command\Command;

$cmd = new Command(\Tivie\Command\ESCAPE);
$cmd->setCommand('C:\Program Files (x86)\DBConvert\SQLite2MySQLSync\SQLite2MySQLSync_Cons.exe')
    ->addArgument(
        new Argument('/Session:"session"')
    );
$result = $cmd->run();
```

`Command::run()` returns a [Result object](https://github.com/tivie/command/blob/master/src/Result.php) that you can access to retrieve the result of the command.

```
echo $result->getStdOut();    // The Standard Output of the command
echo $result->getLastLine();  // The last line of the Standard Output
echo $result->getStdIn();     // The passed standard input
echo $result->getStdErr();    // The standard error
echo $result->getExitCode();  // The command's exit code
```